# LinkGenerator Object is null after initialization Grails 2.4.3

Tags: grails

I am trying to generate the serverBaseUrl and then populate a field with it.
I looked over quite a few instructions on how to use LinkGenerator, but I keep getting a null pointer exception on the LinkGenerator Object.

What I am working with:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator

MyService{
    def linkGenerator

    String client_url = getServerUrl()

    String getServerUrl(){
        linkGenerator.serverBaseURL
    }
}
```

I have tried using LinkGenerator linkGenerator, relocating it, and adding a value to grails.serverURL in Config.groovy. The string client_url is on a trigger, so the method does not get called until after the program is running.

I am using Grails 2.4.3 and Java 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your approach.  One is that you probably want to access the `grailsLinkGenerator` bean.

```
 class MyService {
      def grailsLinkGenerator

       String getServerUrl(){
           grailsLinkGenerator.serverBaseURL
      }
 }
```

In your code you have this:

```
class MyService{
    def linkGenerator

    String client_url = getServerUrl()

    String getServerUrl(){
        linkGenerator.serverBaseURL
    }
}
```

Aside from the bean name problem, yo uare trying to initialize `client_url` before dependency injection has happened.  It isn't clear why you need that property to begin with but if you really do want something like that, try this...

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean

class MyService implements InitializingBean {
    def grailsLinkGenerator
    String client_url

    String getServerUrl(){
        grailsLinkGenerator.serverBaseURL
    }

    void afterPropertiesSet() {
        client_url = getServerUrl()
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that was very thorough .

Answer (score 1):

The bean is actually called `grailsLinkGenerator`, so you need to declare it as `LinkGenerator grailsLinkGenerator` (or `def grailsLinkGenerator`).

I couldn't find the official documentation for it, but check for example http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2012/01/grails-goodness-generate-links-outside.html .